# cURL in not working in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl

cURL is enabled in the server. But it's showing some error from the `curl_exec($curl)` point. No other error is showing from `curl_error($curl);`

> Fatal error: Original Handler not found! in /public_html/curl_test.php on line 18

The cURL package is `curl-7.29.0-46.el7.x86_64`.

Could anyone suggest me any solution or can help me to troubleshoot the issue?

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://someurl.com',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
));


if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Have you tried the exact same code (or as close as possible) in a controlled environment, like your local server?

Comment: The request website has this are original handler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you have any solution for this?

Comment: As with most questions on SO if you show us some relevant code you are more likely to get some useful help

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for your suggestion. I have added the code snippet.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you doing `curl_exec($curl)` twice? I would guess thats your problem

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No dear just test purpose I have written that. From the first line, the errors are coming

Comment: if i read this correctly, when your curl_exec works, first thing you do is to curl_exec again with the same resource `$curl`.  hmmmm. You should read the fabulous manual **[for curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)**.

Comment: As first if you use a curl_exec with that settings you will never get back a true or false

Since the error state about row 18 which is the parentesis after the else likely the code you posted is not complete, so please report the original content of the row which is triggering the error.

Further explanation about return from curl_exec can be found at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452636/php-curl-what-does-curl-exec-return

Comment: This post may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the **zlib.output_compression**.
It fixed and curl is working now.